# wso2 esb drupal connector

Tags: drupal-7, wso2-esb

I have been able to retrieve node data(from the Drupal rest service) using the WSO2 ESB Drupal connector, but while posting data(creating a node), it fails even though it shows response 200 using the rest client. Drupal permissions have been set with anonymous rights for reading and creating node content.

Both the drupal application and the WSO2 ESB application are on my local machine.

ESB URL 10.102.6.223:8280/services/drupal_createNode_jun21-333pm
Drupal Rest API URL  10.102.6.223:8090/drupal/test1

Data posted through the rest client:
    {
    "responseType":"json",
"apiUrl": "http://10.102.6.223:8090/drupal/test1",
"title": "test title213pmv2",
"type": "article"
    }

WSO2 ESB Proxy service details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="drupal_createNode_jun21-333pm" startOnLoad="true"
  trace="disable" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence onError="faultHandlerSeq">
      <sequence key="faultHandlerSeq"/>
      <property expression="json-eval($.responseType)"
        name="responseType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property expression="json-eval($.apiUrl)" name="apiUrl"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property expression="json-eval($.title)" name="title"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property expression="json-eval($.type)" name="type"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <drupal.init>
        <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
        <responseType>{$ctx:responseType}</responseType>
      </drupal.init>
      <drupal.createNode>
        <type>{$ctx:type}</type>
        <title>{$ctx:title}</title>
      </drupal.createNode>
      <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

Any pointers to get this working is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing nodeBody please use below format and try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="drupal_createNode" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
 <target>
 <inSequence onError="faultHandlerSeq">
  <property name="responseType" expression="json-eval($.responseType)"/>
  <property name="apiUrl" expression="json-eval($.apiUrl)"/>
  <property name="userName" expression="json-eval($.userName)"/>
  <property name="password" expression="json-eval($.password)"/>
  <property name="title" expression="json-eval($.title)"/>
  <property name="nodeBody" expression="json-eval($.nodeBody)"/>
  <property name="customFields" expression="json-eval($.customFields)"/>
  <property name="comment" expression="json-eval($.comment)"/>
  <property name="type" expression="json-eval($.type)"/>
  <drupal.init>
     <responseType>{$ctx:responseType}</responseType>
     <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
     <userName>{$ctx:userName}</userName>
     <password>{$ctx:password}</password>
  </drupal.init>
  <drupal.createNode>
     <title>{$ctx:title}</title>
     <nodeBody>{$ctx:nodeBody}</nodeBody>
     <customFields>{$ctx:customFields}</customFields>
     <comment>{$ctx:comment}</comment>
     <type>{$ctx:type}</type>
  </drupal.createNode>
   <respond/>
 </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
   <send/>
  </outSequence>
 </target>
```

and use request in below format

```
{
"apiUrl": "http://172.22.217.40/restapi",
"userName": "samliyanage",
"password": "1qaz2wsx@",
"responseType": "json",
"title": "test title",
"nodeBody": {
    "und": [
        {
            "value": "bodyss textreee",
            "summary": "dffffffffffffff",
            "format": "filtered_html",
            "safe_value": "bodyss text",
            "safe_summary": "text"
        }
    ]
},
"customFields": {
    "field_des": "tiger tiger"
},
"comment": "testing",
"type": "article"
}
```

For more details [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Nodes+in+Drupal#WorkingwithNodesinDrupal-createNode)